# Why is the heap utilisation increasing over time even if my program does not create any new objects?

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

This is a very basic question. But I am not getting any clear answer over internet.
I have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000000);
}
```

I connected JVisualVM and started monitoring the heap usage. I could see that the heap usage is gradually increasing over time. But, here I am not creating any new objects. What could be the reason behind this? Why is the heap utilisation increasing without the creation of any new objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *heap usage is gradually increasing over time*, well by how much? 1%? 5%? 3000%? Why should you care in the first place? The reason could literally be anything. `Thread.sleep()`s invocation probably allocates a timer to know when the sleep is finished: Your VM could've caught a cold. A lot could happen. So there is probably no clear answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have connected with jvisualvm you should be able to see that there are many threads, not only the main application thread. Objects are created all the time. The profiler itself, for example, certainly creates objects. It is normal.

Comment: Ok. the threads that are running in the background (like Finalizer, Attach Listener etc..) are creating those objects. Makes sense. Did not think about it...